# Calling Oracle DB Function with ref cursor as input from Java program

Tags: java, database, function, input, cursor

I am facing this technical challenge first time. I have researched for 3 days before posting this question and have not found any solution yet.

My Problem is "Calling Oracle DB Function (which takes a ref cursor as input parameter) from Java program". In my research I found lot of sample Java code that reads returned ref cursor from DB Function/stored proc but I did not find any sample code to input a ref cursor to the DB function.

Below is my DB Function

```
FUNCTION CheckFileStatus (pUserId     NUMBER, pFileList     FileList) RETURN FilesStatus




  CURSOR curFileList IS
    SELECT file_path, file_name
      FROM file_in_transfer
      WHERE file_in_transfer_id = -1;



TYPE FileList IS REF CURSOR RETURN curFileList%ROWTYPE;
```

Can someone please post some sample Java code to call above DB function?

Thanks,
Srinivas

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`OracleCallableStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/OracleCallableStatement.html) and pass the [`REF`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/sql/REF.html) type on the [`setREF(....)`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/OracleCallableStatement.html#setREF_java_lang_String__oracle_sql_REF_) method..

The downside to this is you're tying yourself to only Oracle JDBC library.

For independent library, use [`CallableStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html), passing the [`Ref`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Ref.html) type on the [`setRef(....)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setRef%28int,%20java.sql.Ref%29) method.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.

I am fine tying my code to Oracle. Could you please post some sample code or direct me to a webpage?

Thanks,
Srinivas

Comment: And I think, this cannot be done independent way as I have to call StructDescriptor.createDescriptor for FileList type.

Comment: I guess you will have to Google, I'm afraid. I haven't played with Oracle `REF` myself.